# URL Pattern Routing MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to know how to have something like this in the url in asp.net MVC

/Article/12.20.2013

I tried below and its working fine for /Article/12-20-2013 but not for /Article/12.20.2013. I have below in the Global.asax

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Blog",
    "/Article/{entryDate}",
    new {controller = "Article", action = "Entry")};
```

I also tried something like below

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Blog",
    "/Article/{month}.{Date}.{year}",
    new {controller = "Article", action = "Entry")};
```

but no luck..

Please guide me with some sample.

Comment: Any chance you are on IIS6?

Comment: You should consider using the first pattern /Article/12-20-2013 as your route as setting RunAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" is not advised as it adds extra overhead by running requests for static files like .html and .jpeg through the ASP.NET pipeline. See [ASP.NET Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc668201%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#configuration_settings_for_routing)

Comment: +1 I was not aware of that. Good to know that Thanks again Anthony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is that IIS might be treating ".2013" as a file extension and trying to find a handler for it. What we need to do is to have MVC process all requests.

If you are on IIS 6 this you will need to do a wildcard mapping to `aspnet_isapi.dll`.  If you are on IIS 7 you can set the `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"`:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: +1 for the answer. can you please tell if this can be done for a specific Controller Views ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change web.config to force every url starting with `Article`  to be treated as a MVC url

```
<system.webServer>    
  <handlers>      
    <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" 
         type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingHandler, 
               System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, 
               Culture=neutral, 
               PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
         path="/Article/*" 
         verb="GET"/>      
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Then your routing should be working fine.

Comment: Already done that but whenever i tried /Article/12.20.2013 it fails where as /Article/12-20-2013 worked fine