# How to redirect to an asp.net mvc 4 controller action a post to a php file

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am building an asp mvc4 website to replace an old php site. There are client applications out in the world that connect to some php files in the old site for various reasons and I have successfully rerouted those using routes.MapRoutes in the RouteConfig file. Each of these are sending data in the url so I can easily catch it like this: filename.php/{dataVar}. However, I find that when I redirect like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "RegisterForm",
    url: "register.php",
    new { controller = "PhpReroutes", action = "RegisterForm" }
```

My browser address is this: 
localhost:55551/register.php and the break point in the action method is never hit.

If I add a slash to the reroute url (url: "register.php/") and to the browser url (localhost:55551/register.php/) the break point is hit. I can't modify the client app so I have to find a way to get the reroute to work without the slash.

I have tried seemingly every configuration, with [HttpPost] above the endpoint method and without, and everything else I could think of.

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

you might want to use something such as

return Redirect("http://www.google.com");

Update

you can write your url routing as:

```
> public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
>     routes.MapPageRoute("",
>         "Category/{action}/{categoryName}",
>         "~/categoriespage.aspx"); }
```

Comment: Where would you suggest I use this since there is no action called by my reroute?

Comment: Notably those are alternatives:1st You can create PHP routing controller and put the data into it. 2nd Create .httpAccess file and add the route here

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at a question I previously answered. I believe the issue is that with the .php extension, MVC is not getting invoked.

Solution would be to have MVC process all requests:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18140497/84395

Comment: I have three other reroutes for .php files that work wonderfully. That isn't the problem.