# Adding MVC4 Route with url token on the left of the URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to define an MVC4 route like this:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                       name: "ClientRoute" ,
                       url: "{currentClient}/{controller}/{action}.nex",
                       defaults: new { controller="Home", action = "Index" }
                    );
```

The url looks like this: http://www.mydomain.com/client34/Users/View.nex

I expect it to go to the users controller and view action but it just complains that it can't find the page.

**UPDATE**

I should have noted this before. The URL I request is:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/client34/Users/View.nex
```

But the url that ASP.Net complains it was unable to find is:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/Users/View.nex
```

**UPDATE 2**

Oddly enough THIS route does work for defaulting to the index action:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                       name: "ClientRoute-Default",
                       url: "{currentClient}/{controller}",
                       defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
                    );
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the ".nex" bit?

Comment: Tried removing the .nex...still page not found

Comment: are you sure, you have userscontroller?
try client34/Home/Index.nex

your code is correct

route order? this must be placed before the default one

Comment: Check the order of your routes. If it's not already, try making this route the very first in your config and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Doesn't work on any of the controllers...gonna add another anomally I noticed...

Comment: I've put it down to the Only route

Comment: If that 2nd route works, sounds to me that it points to controller/action instead of currentclient/controller. It's very odd,  working fine on mine. runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests=true?

Comment: the second route works fine and picks up the correct controller and action. I'm beginning to think something is rewriting the URL...not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem! Thank you everyone who tried to assist!

Our application still uses another routing module from Castle:Monorail and it was rewriting the URLs removing the Client portion of the url before it got to the MVC routing module.

This was causing the routing to fail.

We'll be migrating everything to MVC eventually.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ignore the `.nex` extensions and treat them as normal route URLs not pointing to any specific resources on the server. 
To do so you should add the following line in your routing configuration:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allnex}", new {allnex=@".*\.nex(/.*)?"});
```

Comment: Have you put it above the rest of your routing configuration code?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that the `.nex` extension is bypassing MVC. You need to have MVC handle these requests.

Please take a look at a previous answer to a similar question: [URL Pattern Routing MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18139975/url-pattern-routing-mvc-3/18140497#18140497)

Comment: I had no luck with your suggestion. The routing is working for other types of routing including the .nex extension. It only fails when I try to extract a parameter on the left side of the url